# Group joined data in django

Tags: python, django

Given the following models:

```
class ErrorPhrase(models.Model):
    ...
    document = models.ForeignKey(to=Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    start_index = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    correct_form = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)


class ErrorTag(models.Model):
    ...
    error_phrase = models.ForeignKey(to=ErrorPhrase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    error = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=error_choices)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=category_choices)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=type_choices)
```

I want to retrieve all the ErrorPhrase entries with their associated ErrorTags. I have used the values function like below:

```
error_phrases = ErrorPhrase.objects.values(
       "id", "text", "start_index", "errortag__error", 
       "errortag__category", "errortag__type")
```

But this way I get one row of data for each of different ErrorTags of a particular ErrorPhrase object. For example:

```
[{
    "errortag__error": "S",
    "errortag__type": "WO",
    "errortag__category": "S",
    "text": "test",
    "id": 40,
    "start_index": 463
},
{
    "errortag__error": "T",
    "errortag__type": "OO",
    "errortag__category": "P",
    "text": "test",
    "id": 40,
    "start_index": 463
}...]
```

I'm looking for a way to group the data by ErrorPhrase fields ("id", "text", "start_index") and get all the ErrorTags of a particular ErrorPhrase object in a group. Something like this:

```
[{        
    "text": "test",
    "id": 40,
    "start_index": 463,
    "error_tags": [{
                      "errortag__error": "S",
                      "errortag__type": "WO",
                      "errortag__category": "S"},
                   {
                      "errortag__error": "T",
                      "errortag__type": "OO",
                      "errortag__category": "P"}]
},...]
```

Can I do it in one query using Django QuerySet API ?

Comment: are you using django rest framework?

Comment: @subha.py Yes, I'm using django rest framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit change in your **ErrorTag model**s:

```
class ErrorTag(models.Model):
    ...
    error_phrase = models.ForeignKey(to=ErrorPhrase, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='errortags')
    error = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=error_choices)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=category_choices)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=type_choices)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework.serializers import SerializerMethodField


class ErrorPhraseListSerializer(ModelSerializer):

     error_tags = SerializerMethodField('get_errors') #cannot use get_error_tags here

     def get_errors(self,instance):
        alist = []
        tags_qs = instance.errortags.all()
        for tag in tags_qs:
            alist.append({
                'errortag__error': tag.error,
                'errortag__category':tag.category,
                'errortag__type': tag.type
            })
        return alist

     class Meta:
        model = ErrorPhrase
        fields = [
            'document',
            'text',
            'start_index',
            'correct_form ',
            'error_tags',
         ]
```

Now in your **views.py**

```
class ErrorPhraseListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ErrorPhraseListSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return File.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Comment: according to your code, ErrorPhrases and their associated ErrorTags are now being fetched in one query ? or for fetching ErrorTags of a particular ErrorPhrase we are issuing a new query to database ?

Comment: Two hits are done in the database in the get_queryset function in views and in get_errors function.